# Has anyone seen this in "Folder and search options"

Tags: windows-7

[image: Screen capture]

I've noticed this recently in Windows 7. I don't think it was like that right after I installed it. How can I remove the "ON" and "OFF" after each item in the window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a feature in Windows to make it easier for people using screen readers. You have probably installed some new software that behaves like a screen reader and thus Windows enables those options for you.

You can check your accessibility options under control panel to see if you've enabled anything there or try to figure out which software you installed that caused this issue.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is trying out Microsoft's Speech Recognizer recently. I don't see any setting related to this in the Control Panel.

Comment: That could possibly create this issue. I don't have a mic handy so I can't configure it and test for myself.